# I want to save a CSV with Aggregate Report in JMeter. I need to save this file in my local repository where the JMX file is

Tags: csv, file, jmeter, report, aggregate

I want to save a CSV with Aggregate Report in JMeter. I need to save this file in my local repository where the JMX file is. How I can indicate the path? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the CSV file with Aggregate Report data out of the [.jtl file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) containing your test results using [JMeter Plugins Command Line Graph Plotting Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/)

1. Install JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

   [image]

   you may also need to install [Synthesis Report](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/) if you don't have it
2. [Run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
3. Once your test is complete you can generate Aggregate Report CSV representation as follows:

   ```
   JMeterPluginsCMD --generate-csv aggregate-report.csv --input-jtl result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
   ```

   this `aggregate-report.csv` is a relative path to the current folder, you can make it absolute like:

   ```
   JMeterPluginsCMD --generate-csv c:/somefolder/someotherfolder/aggregate-report.csv --input-jtl result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
   ```

More information: [How to Use the JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line)